# R Grouping data from dataframes for data analysis

Tags: r, dataframe, select, genetic-programming

I need help with that because I do not know how to handle this. I have 2 dataframes, they look like this:

(df1) DataGenSample: each column is a sample and the first one is the gene

[image]

(df2) Subtypes: a df of 2 columns, the 1st col is the sample and the 2nd col is a subtype of cancer

[image]

The first thing what i'm looking for is to select only the matching samples of DataGenSample from subtypes, and then separate them with its subtype.

The data files can be found [here](https://www.transfernow.net/x09ZvB042020)

Any help is more than welcome! because I'm lost.

```
DataGenSample <- read.table("DataGenSample.txt",sep="\t", header=TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
Subtypes <- read.table("SamplesType.txt",sep="\t", header=TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
```

A little example:
df1:

```
hugo_symbol   TCGA-3C-AAAU-01    TCGA-3C-AALI-01    TCGA-3C-AALJ-01 ... TCGA-3C-AALL-99
CDK11A               0                 -1                -1         ...     -1
HNRNPR               0                 -1                -1         ...     -1
SRSF10               0                 -1                -1         ...     -1
```

df2:

```
Sample_id            Subtype
TCGA-3C-AAAU-01        BRCA_LumA
TCGA-3C-AALI-01        BRCA_Her2
TCGA-3C-AALL-99        BRCA_Normal
```

Output Expected:

-BRCA_LumA.df:

```
hugo_symbol   TCGA-3C-AAAU-01    
CDK11A               0              
HNRNPR               0              
SRSF10               0
```

-BRCA_Her2.df:

```
hugo_symbol   TCGA-3C-AALI-01   
CDK11A               -1              
HNRNPR               -1              
SRSF10               -1
```

-BRCA_Normal.df:

```
hugo_symbol   TCGA-3C-AALL-99   
CDK11A               -1              
HNRNPR               -1              
SRSF10               -1
```

Comment: the sample_id, that is the header of the df1

Comment: @akrun I've just write a little example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to select a subset of columns from DataGenSample corresponsding to a certain subtype in the Subtypes. This can be achieved by pivoting the columns to rows using `pivot_longer()` from tidyr package (name was `gather()` in older versions). After the pivot you can join the two data frames on SAMPLE_ID.

You can now filter on subtype and the SAMPLE_IDs (now less in number) can be pivoted back to columns. 
You can do this for all subtypes separately using a for loop, using `assign()` to name to data frame according to the subtype in the filter.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DataGenSample_long <- DataGenSample %>% 
  pivot_longer(names_to = 'SAMPLE_ID', values_to = 'value', cols = -Hugo_Symbol) 

DataGenSample_long_join <- DataGenSample_long %>% 
  left_join(Subtypes, by = 'SAMPLE_ID')

for (Subtype in unique(Subtypes$SUBTYPE)) {
  assign(paste0(Subtype,'.df'), 
         DataGenSample_long_join %>% 
           filter(SUBTYPE == Subtype) %>% 
           select(-SUBTYPE) %>% 
           pivot_wider(names_from = SAMPLE_ID, values_from = value))
}
```

Comment: great! I did not know about pivot_longer(), indeed I was thinking to tranpose the dataframe or somthing, very nice! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If we need to create a `list` of `data.frame`s based on the 'Subtype', we can do a `split` of 'Sample_id' by 'Subtype' into a `list`  of `vector`s, use that names to select the columns of the first dataset along with 'hugo_symbol'

```
lst1 <-  lapply(split(df2$Sample_id, df2$Subtype), 
         function(nm) df1[c("hugo_symbol", nm)])
lst1
#$BRCA_Her2
#  hugo_symbol TCGA-3C-AALI-01
#1      CDK11A              -1
#2      HNRNPR              -1
#3      SRSF10              -1

#$BRCA_LumA
#  hugo_symbol TCGA-3C-AAAU-01
#1      CDK11A               0
#2      HNRNPR               0
#3      SRSF10               0

#$BRCA_Normal
#  hugo_symbol TCGA-3C-AALL-99
#1      CDK11A              -1
#2      HNRNPR              -1
#3      SRSF10              -1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(hugo_symbol = c("CDK11A", "HNRNPR", "SRSF10"), 
    `TCGA-3C-AAAU-01` = c(0L, 0L, 0L), `TCGA-3C-AALI-01` = c(-1L, 
    -1L, -1L), `TCGA-3C-AALJ-01` = c(-1L, -1L, -1L), `TCGA-3C-AALL-99` = c(-1L, 
    -1L, -1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df2 <- structure(list(Sample_id = c("TCGA-3C-AAAU-01", "TCGA-3C-AALI-01", 
"TCGA-3C-AALL-99"), Subtype = c("BRCA_LumA", "BRCA_Her2", "BRCA_Normal"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: The point is to figure out another way when you have more than 300 samples, because type one per one ....

Comment: @WindSur can you be more clear.  You don't need `select` specifically?

Comment: @WindSur if you can upddate with the expected ouptut, it becomes more clear

Comment: the first point is to select all the matching samples form the df2, and then regroup with the different subtypes of df2

Comment: @WindSur not clear.  can you please update with a ssmall expected output

Comment: thanks! But if you have already the files in txt, how do you import them to a list? because I've tried to convert my dataframes in a list vector but unsuccessfully :(